# How to add text to paragraphs similar to table cells

Tags: python, logic, python-docx

First time posting on SE so apologies for wonky formatting. I am a novice python and the python-docx module so I may be missing something basic in my code. Essentially, I am trying to include an "add_paragraph" inside a for loop so that every run through the loop it will add +1 value to the paragraph text.

I have been able to iterate through a table's cells similar to this:

```
document= document(filename.docx)

for x in range(0,3): ##creates 3 tables
     table = document.add_table(rows=3,cols=3)

for y in range(0,3):
     for z in range(0,3):
          tablecells = document.tables[x].rows[y].cells
          tablecells[0].text = 'Column 0, cell %d' % (z)
```

The out put of this code would give me something like this in the first column of the first table:

```
|------------------|--------------|---------|
|Column 0, cell 0  |              |         |
|------------------|--------------|---------|
|Column 0, cell 1  |              |         |
|------------------|--------------|---------|
|Column 0, cell 2  |              |         |
|------------------|--------------|---------|
```

So this method works great for populating a table with pre known values.

I would like to know if there's a way to do this with paragraphs instead of table cells. My pseudo code would be something like this:

```
for x in range(1,4):
     document.add_paragraph('This is paragraph %d') % (x)
```

My expected result is this:

```
This is paragraph 1

This is paragraph 2

This is paragraph 3
```

However, if try to run this code I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Paragraph' and 'int'
```

I hope I made this clear and thank you in advance for any help and knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
for x in range(1,4):
     document.add_paragraph('This is paragraph %d') % (x)
```

to

```
for x in range(1,4):
     document.add_paragraph('This is paragraph %d' % (x))
```

The 1st piece of code tries to implement the % operator on the result of document.add_paragraph('This is paragraph %d') and x which should be the Paragraph (object) that is mentioned in the error.

while the second piece is what you want , namely apply % operator on a string and replace the %d with the value of x.

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted! Can you explain why it works or what I was doing wrong?

Comment: document.add_paragraph('This is paragraph %d') % (x) --> in this code , document.add_paragraph('This is paragraph %d')  is executed first and then % operator is applied on the result of that.

Comment: what you want is ('this is para %d' % x) to be executed first , so we wrap that piece of code into the inner parantheses / bracket

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up. Simple error of not understanding the code is executed.